# I have this two collections namely Inward and Outward, Both collections have similar embeded sub documents contains product, batch and quantity fields

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Inward collections

```
{"ord" : 1,
    "products" : [
            {
                    "name" : "apple",
                    "qty" : "10",
                    "batch" : "jun-2021"
            },
            {
                    "name" : "banana",
                    "qty" : 20,
                    "batch" : "jan-2021"
            }
    ]
```

}

outward collections

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5edde5487957d9efea972a74"),
    "inv" : 1,
    "products" : [
            {
                    "name" : "apple",
                    "qty" : 13,
                    "batch" : "jun-2021"
            }
    ]
```

}

Now, I would like to perform actual stock quantity check for particular product and batch (grouping together) both the collections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this way:

1. We join them with `inward.ord = outward.inv` condition.
2. Flatten `products` field.
3. Group by product's `name` and `batch` to sum `qty` value.

---

```
db.inward.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "outward",
      let: {
        ord: "$ord",
        products: "$products"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [ "$$ord", "$inv" ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            products: {
              $concatArrays: [
                "$$products",
                "$products"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $unwind: "$products"
        },
        {
          $replaceWith: "$products"
        }
      ],
      as: "products"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$products"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        batch: "$products.batch",
        name: "$products.name"
      },
      qty: {
        $sum: "$products.qty"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yfTPWSeAKNS)

**Note:** You need to have MongoDB `v4.2`